# Почему не считывает double переменные с консоли?

Tags: java, double, scanner

С консоли нужно считать переменную типа double, затем умножить ее на 6, округлить в меньшую сторону, результат поместить в переменную типа int и вывести ее увеличив на 1. Но когда попробовал сделать так :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Training {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = read.nextInt();
        double d;
        int c;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            d = read.nextDouble();
            c = (int) Math.floor(d * 6);
            System.out.print(c + 1 + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Выходила ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException  
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)  
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)  
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)  
at Training.main(Training.java:9)
```

Потом попробовал такой способ:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Training {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = read.nextInt();
        double d;
        int c;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (read.hasNextDouble()) {
                d = read.nextDouble();
                c = (int) Math.floor(d * 6);
                System.out.print(c + 1 + " ");
            }else{
                System.out.print(read.hasNextDouble()+" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но на выводе получал все false. 
Входные выглядят примерно так:
24
0.686441579368
0.938021477312
0.502164815553
0.751931000501
0.894581723958
0.417603249196
0.258755513933
0.887455070391
0.818552840035
0.186583039351
0.320293535013
0.449393435847
0.216721537057
0.529250661843
0.377481672913
0.441697923467
0.290121383499
0.121791416779
0.935049816035
0.912419347558
0.777843158692
0.23243222991
0.00152469752356
0.409032049123

Что не так?

Comment: а что вводите то?

Comment: как и где вы запускали программу?

Comment: Запускал в Intellij IDEA 2017.2

Comment: вы вводили **.** (точка) или **,** (запятая)?

Comment: Разделял точкой

Comment: попробуйте из командной строки запустить

Comment: пробовал воспроизвести ошибку - не получилось https://asciinema.org/a/PN1zv05X74toKiDtzgR6LcIrH

Comment: Как я понимаю эта ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException возникает, если не проверять возможность ввода double методом hasNextDouble()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InputMismatchException -- if the next token does not match the Float regular expression, or is out of range

То есть значит, что то-то не так с форматом чисел. Я посмотрел в онлайн компиляторе все работало. А в Intellij IDEA такая появляется  из-за того, что стоят точки,  а нужны запятые. С запятыми все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте локаль US, тогда в формате ввода числа можно вместо запятой указывать точку:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```